# Inuit QuickBooks Token Renewal and Expiration

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am using QB desktop edition. and I wanted to renew/regenerate  'Access Tokens'/'Access Token Secrete' for my QuickBooks desktop edition as they are getting expired in 180 days and  renewal must be made within 30 days of token expiry.
I have tried the same with below code but its not working,  gives error as,

```
<RestResponse xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2"><Error RequestId="14aa97c48321489db48254e4bdb25d00"><RequestName>ErrorRequest</RequestName><ProcessedTime>2013-04-05T11:43:08+00:00</ProcessedTime><ErrorCode>401</ErrorCode><ErrorDesc>Invalid security token</ErrorDesc></Error></RestResponse>
```

There is no any logged  Request/Response for the token generatetion.

```
 string myRealmId = "000000000000000";
        string myAccessToken = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000";
        string myAccessTokenSecret = "00000000000000000000000000000000000";

        string myAppToken = "00000000000000000000000000000000000";
        string myConsumerKey ="00000000000000000000000000000000000";
        string myConsumerSecret ="00000000000000000000000000000000000";

        OAuthConsumerContext consumerContext = new OAuthConsumerContext
        {
            ConsumerKey =myConsumerKey,
            SignatureMethod = SignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
            ConsumerSecret = myConsumerSecret
        };

        OAuthSession oSession = new OAuthSession(consumerContext, "https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token",
                        "https://workplace.intuit.com/Connect/Begin",
                        "https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_access_token");

        oSession.ConsumerContext.UseHeaderForOAuthParameters = true;

        oSession.AccessToken = new TokenBase
        {
            Realm = myRealmId,
            Token = myAccessToken,
            ConsumerKey = myConsumerKey,
            TokenSecret = myAccessTokenSecret
        };

        var body = "<AdvancedReportQuery xmlns=\"http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2 ..//RestDataFilter.xsd\"><BalanceSheetStd><OfferingId>ipp</OfferingId><EndTransactionDate>2012-06-01</EndTransactionDate></BalanceSheetStd></AdvancedReportQuery>";

        IConsumerRequest conReq = oSession.Request();
        conReq = conReq.Post().WithRawContentType("text/xml").WithRawContent(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(body)); 
        conReq = conReq.ForUrl("https://services.intuit.com/sb/advancedreport/v2/508053445");
        try
        {
            conReq = conReq.SignWithToken();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {}

        string serviceResponse = conReq.ReadBody();

        }
        catch (Exception Err) {}

    }
```

Thanks,

Reshma D.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call the Reconnect API within 30 days prior to token expiration.  It looks like your tokens have already expired, so you will need to go through the Oauth flow again.

http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0060_Reference/3002_Reconnect_API

C# example using DevDefined and DevKit:

https://gist.github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/5338762

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Can you help us to call this API through data service. Like we call data service methods for example ,Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Customer qbdCustomer = dataServices.FindById<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Customer>(qbdCustomer1);  Thanks for your reply. Can you help us to call this API through data service. Like we call data service methods for example ,

Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Customer qbdCustomer = dataServices.FindById<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Customer>(qbdCustomer1);
We are not able to figure out which Intuit Quickbooks object would help us for implementaion.Thanks in advance, Reshma D.

Comment: This call is not available in the DevKit.  I have updated the answer above with an example of how to use DevDefined to call the API.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I will try with given reference.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way that you can can always access the same company every time you start up the application. This took me some time to figure out. However I did this in node js; the concept still holds for any programming language.

```
'use strict';

var request = require('request');
var qs = require('querystring');
var config = require('./environment');
var QuickBooks = require('node-quickbooks');

var postBody = {
  url: QuickBooks.REQUEST_TOKEN_URL,
  oauth: {
    // This callback url is just a placeholder so QuickBooks doesn't get upset
    callback: "http://localhost:9000/oauth/quickbooks/callback",
    consumer_key:    config.quickbooks.consumerKey, 
    consumer_secret: config.quickbooks.consumerSecret
  }
}
request.post(postBody, function (e, r, data) {
  var requestToken = qs.parse(data)

  var postBody = {
    url: QuickBooks.ACCESS_TOKEN_URL,
    oauth: {
      consumer_key:    config.quickbooks.consumerKey,
      consumer_secret: config.quickbooks.consumerSecret,
      token:           requestToken.oauth_token,
      token_secret:    requestToken.oauth_token_secret,
      verifier:        config.quickbooks.companyId, // This part is key
      realmId:         config.quickbooks.companyId
    }
  }
  request.post(postBody, function (e, r, data) {
    var accessToken = qs.parse(data)

    GLOBAL.qbo = new QuickBooks(config.quickbooks.consumerKey,
                             config.quickbooks.consumerSecret,
                             accessToken.oauth_token,
                             accessToken.oauth_token_secret,
                             config.quickbooks.companyId,
                             true);
    console.log('Quickbooks Integration Complete');
  })
})
```